# How to lauch a iPhone X session in AWS device farm?

Tags: amazon-web-services

When launch a session in AWS device farm, I can't find a device of iPhone X or any iOS 11 devices.

But in the device info list page, iPhone X does list there http://awsdevicefarm.info/

Where I missed?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because iPhoneX it's not available for Remote Access, like this one:
[Remote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUgK7.png)

I could not find when it's going to be available either...